# Syntax highlighting for domain-specific language in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, editor, syntax-highlighting

I have a domain-specific language with a certain syntax. Is it possible to make Visual Studio 2008 recognize custom languages in the usual editors? That is, associate a given file extension to a certain syntax-coloring scheme? If so, would you have any pointers as to how to do this?

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. I searched but couldn't find a relevant answer, and yet it does sound like a simple question.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the [Implementing Color Syntax Highlighting in Visual Studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165041.aspx) seems like the deep end, you can download the Lua Lang Pack http://luaforge.net/projects/lualangpack/ and see how they do it.

They use the [Compiler Tools in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/malcolmcrowe/CsTools12062005231835PM/CsTools.aspx) which are quite neat.

Failing that you can download my prototype [Erlang VS plugin](http://code.google.com/p/vs-erlang/) that currently only has simple syntax highlighting, but is based on all the above.

Answer (score 2):

Dervin,

This should help you out:

Implementing Color Syntax Highlighting in Visual Studio 2008: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165041.aspx